# restrict from login after reset password laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5.6

I'm using laravel-5.6 default authentication system for resetting password,registration and login (`php artisan make:auth`). In password reset, when i reset password successfully, it authenticate me and redirect me to next page. As well as in registration doing same thing. How can i restrict those to authenticate me after reset/registration? I want it to direct me back to '/' route with a flash message. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Password Reset:

In (lluminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php) there is a function called 'reset' that is responsible to login after resetting the password.
In your ResetPasswordConroller you can override this function by creating a new function as follows.

```
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, $this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
    );

    
    return 'whatever you wanna return.'
}
```

I don't have the code for registration controller but you can override the method by using same method mentioned above.

Comment: it still logged me in.

Comment: Thanks for your details. the location helped me to figure it out.

Comment: The function that helped me was resetPassword(). In resetPassword() i comment out this line $this->guard()->login($user) which was the reason for login after password reset.

Comment: I won't recommend you commenting the line in trait. Create a function in ResetPasswordController.php under Controllers folder as follows.

    protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
    {
        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));

        $user->save();

        event(new PasswordReset($user));

       
    }

This is will override the function in trait.